# AMPscript feedback on MobileConnect OptOut for multiple subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I have a MobileConnect model where a subscriber could exist multiple times.
The below code works, but will only process one row instead of all of them.
 (the context is a text-response sms).

Can anybody see any potential error, why the for loop doesn't process multiple records?

```
 %%[
var @contactId, @subscriberKey, @MobileNumber, @Status, @LOB, @Dato, @DeltaDE, @PermissionDE, @HistoryDE, @ContactRows, @ContactRow

SET @PermissionDE = 'SMS_Permissions'
SET @DeltaDE = 'SMS_Permissions_Delta'
SET @HistoryDE = 'SMS_Permissions_History'
SET @Status = "OptOut"
SET @LOB = "Business"
SET @Dato = NOW()

IF @Status == "OptIn" THEN
    SET @OptIn = "True"
    ELSE
    SET @OptIn = "False"
ENDIF

SET @MobileNumber = MOBILE_NUMBER

SET @ContactRows = LookupRows(@PermissionDE,"Mobile",@MobileNumber,"SMS_OptIn","True")

IF RowCount(@ContactRows) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to rowcount(@ContactRows) DO
        SET @ContactRows = LookupRows(@PermissionDE,"Mobile",@MobileNumber,"SMS_OptIn","True")
        SET @ContactRow = Row(@ContactRows, 1)
        SET @subscriberKey = Field(@ContactRow,"SFID_Contact")

    /* Update Permission DE */
    UpsertData(@PermissionDE, 1,"SFID_Contact", @subscriberKey, "Telefon_Mobil", @MobileNumber, "SMS_OptIn", @OptIn)

    /* Update Permission Delta */
    UpsertData(@DeltaDE, 2,"SFID_Contact", @subscriberKey, "LOB", @LOB, "Mobile", @MobileNumber, "Status", @Status, "Dato", @Dato)

    /* Update Permission History */
    InsertData(@HistoryDE, "SFID_Contact", @subscriberKey, "Mobile", @MobileNumber, "Status", @Status, "LOB", @LOB, "Dato", @Dato)
    NEXT @i
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out based on the [old exacttarget help page](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_401/). Essentially it was an error in how i processed the "SET Contact Row" stuff.. Look below for the right statement. I changed the following:

```
IF RowCount(@ContactRows) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to rowcount(@ContactRows) DO
        SET @ContactRows = LookupRows(@PermissionDE,"Mobile",@MobileNumber,"SMS_OptIn","True")
        SET @ContactRow = Row(@ContactRows, 1)
        SET @subscriberKey = Field(@ContactRow,"SFID_Contact")
```

Into this:

```
IF RowCount(@ContactRows) > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to rowcount(@ContactRows) DO
        SET @ContactRow = Row(@ContactRows,@i)
        SET @subscriberKey = Field(@ContactRow,"SFID_Contact")
```